# Using SSD cache to install another OS

Tags: windows-8.1, ssd, multi-boot, hard-drive-cache

So I been given a laptop at work that has a slow HDD with a separated NGFF-type SSD as cache for windows 8.1, but as it turns out the SSD has 128GB and windows can only use up to 64GB for cache meaning there are an unused 64GB there. I been thinking that I could partition those 64GB out and install linux there but since the laptop isn't mine I would like to know if it could interfere with any windows cache functions because I have to keep this partition and windows its damn slow without that cache.

Comment: How are the partitions listed in `diskmgmt.msc`?